# VSCode extension to switch between frameworks and connected projects

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

[image: Look next to TODOs]

In VSCode, there used to be a button next to TODOs which I could click to switch between framework and base code. (they are in separate commits and folders etc).
It would drop a menu down similar to hitting CMD+p for recently opened files.
Except this was something like connected frameworks?
I've tried unsuccessfully to find a plugin that I might have disabled. 
And Google was not help -- probably not wording my search properly.

Anyone know if that is a setting or a plugin and how to re-enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH HA!
It is called "Project Manager" and is an extension available for VSCode.
SUPER HELPFUL. (I've removed the paths from this screenshot for privacy. But they do work).

[image: choosing project framework]

[image: VSCode Extension : Project Manager]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Extension profile](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cyberbiont.vscode-profiles) extension to create extension profile system
so you can switch between profiles to disable unwanted extensions at once Here how i use -

- While doing c++ projects, I use 'cppProfile' a profile which has cpp related extensions only which I've manually added in 'cppProfile' it disables unwanted extensions
- While web development, I use 'WebD' a profile which has web development related extensions only like auto rename,live server and similar extensions

For information on how use this extension read [Extension profile](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cyberbiont.vscode-profiles) overview section Thank You!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186027/how-to-create-different-environments-to-code-in-vs-code-e-g-by-language-se/72875272#72875272