# How to create different environments to code in VS Code (e.g. :by language). [Settings Profiles]

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ide

I want to have custom settings for each library in VS Code.

For example, I want to enable a plugin in all my React projects but not in Vue JS.

I don't want to do it manually, is there a thing to switch settings?

I don't want the IDE automatically detect it, I want to create customized settings and switch between them when I need to.

Comment: create workspaces, you can enable/disable extension per workspace

Answer (score 6):

There is more settings profiles support in v1.71, see [v1.71 Release Notes: Settings Profiles](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_71.md#settings-profiles)

> In this milestone, we added CLI support for Settings Profiles feature.
> You can now pass the name of the profile using `--profile` arg and open
> a folder or a workspace using that profile. Following instruction
> opens the web-sample folder with the Web Development profile. If the
> profile does not exist, a new empty profile with the given name is
> created.
>
> `code ~/projects/web-sample --profile "Web Development"`
>
> We also added support for Temporary Settings Profile that can be
> created and associated to a folder or workspace temporarily. This
> profile gets auto deleted once it is not associated to any folder or
> workspace.

---

Expanded support for "profiles" will be in a preview state in vscode v1.69.  From [release notes: settings profiles](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#settings-profiles):

> A Settings Profile comprises of settings, keyboard shortcuts,
> extensions, state, tasks, and snippets. You can customize VS Code for
> different development environments like Web, Machine Learning, or for
> multiple programming language classrooms like Python, Java or for
> personal modes like Work or Demo and save them as Settings Profiles.
> You can open multiple workspaces (folders) with different profiles
> simultaneously based on the projects you are working on or the
> classroom you are attending to or when you are presenting.
>
> Below demonstrates customizing VS Code for web development environment
> and creating a settings profile out of it.

[image: demo of settings profiles]

[more gifs from the release notes omitted here]

> You can open your `React` project in web development profile and `Python`
> class project in `Python` class profile simultaneously as shown in the
> following picture.

[image: different programming environments for different languages]

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "statusBarItem.settingsProfilesBackground": "#ce4918",
    "statusBarItem.settingsProfilesForeground": "#e0dfdb",
}
```

> You can manage and remove settings profiles using the `Remove Settings Profile...` action available in the `Settings Profiles` sub menu in
> `Settings` gear menu.
>
> Even though you can customize VS Code per profile, there are some
> which can be customized only at application level. For example, all
> application scoped settings like `update.mode`, language pack
> extensions, settings sync enablement and workspace trust state shall
> be customized across all profiles at application level.

Comment: set workbench.experimental.settingsProfiles.enabled=true

Comment: Another vote for Profiles. I provided more notes about this in another answer today. I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77019512/190955

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **.vscode** folder in each and every project you build,
and add your customized **setting.json** for every project

reference https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

my .vscode/setting.json

```
{
  "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZF8C.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mentioned, we can create  different workspaces, but this is not ideal for me!

So I found these extensions that you can create profiles and switch between them quickly.

I found these useful:

1.[Profile Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaronpowell.vscode-profile-switcher)
2.[Extension profiles](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cyberbiont.vscode-profiles)