# Is there a way to toggle VS Code extensions per project?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

While working with multiple Vue JS projects (Vue 2 & Vue 3), it is recommended to use a different extensions based on the version your using.
Vue 2 = Vetur
Vue 3 = Volar

Is there a way to auto-enable/disable these extensions from either `settings.json` or vscode itself?

maybe something like:

```json
// settings.json
{
  "extensions": {
    "Vetur": false,
    "Volar": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72875272/836330 for "settings profiles" which allow you to have different sets of extensions for different projects.  Also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#settings-profiles

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can actually - if you go into the extension settings, you have an option to enable/disable just for the current workspace:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is by using [DevContainer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers). This means that you can have project-based customization in `devcontainer.json` for everybody in the team or who cloning the project. This requires docker installed.

This way you can keep your Visual Studio with minimal common extensions, and the rest put inside `devcontainer.json` for each project.

This is how you create [DevContainer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container).

The good thing is, that it starts the workspace in an isolated development environment and will only include what you customize it for, for instance, extensions. The downside, it can take longer the first time, hence it will take time to create a docker image.

Both links are official documentation for Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

Say I'm working with some Vendor extension and they update that.  I've got multiple projects going and some of them can use the updates and some of them can't (at present) so I have to keep all this stuff around basically forever.

I have to have different workspaces per project anyway (these settings would need to be transmitted into the repo along with the code itself) so this isn't too bad other than attempting to figure out which extensions are from Vendor A and which ones are from Vendor B (ner the two mix -- they will have different compiler chains for instance)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34824723)