# Can you have isolated VS Code environments so each project has its own extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work on multiple projects in VS code. Over time and across projects I have accumulated so many extensions so that starting up is slower and some extensions cause things to break so I have to reinstall VS code to open up a project.

Is there a way, similar to python venv, where you have have multiple instances of vs code each with its own set of extensions?

Comment: See Profiles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186027/how-to-create-different-environments-to-code-in-vs-code-e-g-by-language-se/72875272?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.8989#72875272

Comment: Agreement with @starball and I posted an answer on the topic he linked. HTH

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can disable/enable extensions per *workspace*! Not quite the same as install/uninstall but should solve your problem of extensions running on startup

You go to extensions menu, click the gear icon on some installed extension and you can `Disable (Workspace)`. You can do the same in reverse for enabling per workspace - [docs here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_disable-an-extension).

Answer (score 0):

1. use profiles. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles.
2. I think you can check another possible reason, because mosty extensions have a setting named Activation Events which you can see in the end of the extension home page - FEATURE CONTRIBUTIONS. The extensions are active under certain conditions, and when they are inactive, they do not consume excessive resources.